# How can I run a background service in the admin backend?

Tags: mage-googleshopping

I noticed the following in `Mage_GoogleShopping`:

- I can add products to Google
- Now an info is displayed "Synchronization is in progress"
- I can leave the backend page and if I come back later, the process was finished.

How can this be implemented in an own extension?

I do not think it is done by a server side cron job, because the job seems to start very soon after I hit "submit".

And it can not be done in the webserver process, because I can close the browser and it continues its work.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Most likely the key is on line 123 of `controllers/Adminhtml/Googleshopping/ItemsController.php`:

```
ignore_user_abort(true);
```

Answer (score 1):

I never looked at Mage_GoogleShopping but as far as I know closing the browser won't stop the request that is being processed ([this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11360274/can-closing-the-browser-terminate-the-php-script-on-the-server) would support my guess) so it would be simple to implement an ajax call that would start synchronization and return a response when it would end so that the browser can show it to the user.